# Вывод js-переменной в input

Tags: input, javascript

```
<p><input type="submit" value="Считать" onclick="someFunc()"></p>
результат:<input id="rezult" >

<script>var gt;
function someFunc(){qt = 1231321;}</script>
```

Скрипт вызывается по нажатию кнопки.

Мне нужно, чтобы значение переменной `gt` выводилось в `input id="rezult"`,
но она появляется и сразу исчезает. Ничего не могу с этим поделать.
Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<p><input type="submit" value="Считать" onclick="someFunc()" /></p>
результат:<input id="rezult" >
```

JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById('rezult');

function someFunc(){
    el.value = 1231321;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vstak8ae/

Сейчас не рекомендуется использовать атрибуты onclick и т.д. Лучше через обработчики событий типа `addEventListener` и т.д.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, мой скрипт (калькулятор комплексных чисел), я поправил, но мне теперь пишет, нужно использовать пост метод, если его использовать, то пишет какую-то не известную мне ошибку... Я только начинаю пользоваться js. http://jsfiddle.net/6f3L1chk/

Comment: @poltos-15, на глаз так нету брейков, кейсы сами не останавливаются, смекаешь?

Comment: да это пока недоделанный вариант)) refactoring еще не было... Вот теперь именно с выводом в поле не могу разобраться. Понять не могу, что в конструкции неправильно, что вывод сбрасывается... Код в дальнейшем поправлю)

Answer (score -1):

У тебя кнопка типа *submit*. Он перезагружает страницу. Поменяй на *button*