# JavaScript калькулятор. Ввод чисел и вывод ответа

Tags: javascript, html

Пишу в первый раз калькулятор на JavaScript. Столкнулся с проблемой: не знаю как передать из полей ввода первое и второе слагаемое в переменные скрипта, а так же как потом вывести ответ

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Калькулятор</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Введите 1 и 2 число</h1>
    <div class="mainn">
        <input type="text" name="first" size="10">
        <p>+</p>
        <input type="text" name="second" size="10"><br>
        <button>=</button><br>
        <h1></h1> <!--//ответ -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a1 , a2;
        var a3 = a1 + a2;
        //как мне вывести ответ?
    </script>
</body> </html>
```

**style.css** //вдруг он тоже важен

```
    body{
    background-color: wheat;
}
    .mainn{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Я просто оставлю тут:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/407205/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-js-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-input https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/410765/%D0%92%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function sum(){
  var s1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value);
  var s2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value);
  var s3 = s1 + s2;
  var rez = document.getElementById("rez").innerText = s3;
}
document.getElementById("go").onclick = function() {
  sum();
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: wheat;
}
.mainn{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Калькулятор</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Введите 1 и 2 число</h1>
    <div class="mainn">
        <input type="text" id="first" size="10">
        <p>+</p>
        <input type="text" id="second" size="10"><br>
        <button id="go">=</button><br>
        <h1 id="rez"></h1> <!--//ответ -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: что означет кусок кода, выделенный курсивом  document.getElementById("go").onclick **= function()** ? Это значит что при нажатии могут выполняться ток функции?

Comment: @WetSnaider этот кусок кода навешивает обработчик на кнопку по событию onclick, т.е. при нажатии на кнопку будет вызвана функция sum(), эту функцию можно вызвать по другому `<button onclick="sum();">=</button>`, но такую запись советуют избегать.

Comment: спасибо что объяснил

Comment: А почему калькулятор не считает 0,05+0,11=???

Comment: @Сергей потому что я перевожу входящие данные в целочисленный тип, тебе нужен вещественный parseFloat() вместо parseInt()